# rails resque-web gem versions out of sync with bundled gem versions, How to tell resque-web to use correct gem versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

How do I tell resque-web to use the correct gem versions of rack, sinatra and vegas?
I'm trying to solve undefined method `process_route error when I access resque-web

If I run bundle I get

```
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using sinatra (1.3.3) 
Using vegas (0.1.11) 
Using resque (1.23.0) 
Using rufus-scheduler (2.0.17) 
Using resque-scheduler (2.0.0) from https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler.git (at master)
```

which are the correct versions of the gems that resque-web should be using, however when I run `resque-web -v` I get

```
rack 1.1
sinatra 1.0
vegas 0.1.8
```

which is causing me a massive headache with (assumption that this is the cause)

```
undefined method `process_route' for #<Resque::Server:0xbc22f94>
```

when I try to access resque web in my browser

If I run

```
bundle exec resque-web -v
```

I get

```
rack 1.1
sinatra 1.3.3
vegas 0.1.11
```

Which is still the wrong version of rack.

I'm mounting resque server with the following route

```
mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque", :constraints => AdminRestriction
```

I'm running an nginx, unicorn setup in a rails 3.2.9 app with ruby 1.9.3 and rvm to manage project specific gemsets

This is a production server only problem, everything is fine on my dev PC

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the resque-web gem installed in the system, but not in your bundle.  This is causing it to load an incompatible version, even though you ran `bundle exec`.

You should be able to resolve this by adding resque-web to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem "resque-web"
```

The `bundle exec` command will look into the bundle for the binary/script first, and execute the bundled version.  However, if the gem isn't in the bundle it'll fall back on a binary/bundle on the system.